# HTML Header bottom border does not wrap arround ToC, but the text does. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I've got a ToC (Table of Content) table that's implemented as a Div. It uses the following HTML and CSS:

```css
h3.articletitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

h4.articlesubtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

h5.articlesubtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

#toc_container {
    background: rgba(92, 9, 0, 0.14);
    border: 1px solid #4F120B;
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
<h3 class="articletitle">Title</h3>
<article>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: auto;" id="toc_container">
<p class="toc_title">Contents</p>
<ul class="toc_list">
<li><a  href="#Scociety">Scociety</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#ArtHistory">Art</a></li>
<li><a href="#PopCulture">Pop Culture</a></li>
<li><a href="#HighCulture">High Culture</a></li>
<li><a href="#CommunicationAndTheSpreadOfIdeas">Communication And The Spread Of Ideas</a></li>
<li><a href="#Holidays">Holidays</a></li>
<li><a href="#GenderAndGenderRoles">Gender and Gender Roles</a></li>
<li><a href="#SubculturesAndAlternativeLifestyles">Subcultures and Alternative Lifestyles</a></li>
<li><a href="#UniversalFears">Universal Fears</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<h4 class="articlesubtitle" id="Scociety">Scociety</h4>
<h5 class="articlesubtitle" id="ArtHistory">Art</h5>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

You can see how the border under the headers extends under the ToC's div. How do I get them to wrap with the text? I tried putting them in their own divs and adjusting the width via percentages, but that only worked fullscreen. When resizing, the borders will poke back into the ToC.

I'm new to web design, please keep explanations noob friendly.

Comment: take a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Intro_to_formatting_contexts  ( then you should be able to get your non floating boxes away of floatting ones ).

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Changing the indicated properties on either div didn't do anything. But "overflow: hidden;" does. So thanks!

Comment: overflow is one of the properties to use to modify the formating context, and the one usually first picked up. It was easy to answser, but what matters is that you understand how to deal with floats and what formating context involves ;) the link says (among the list) " **block elements where overflow has a value other than visible** "

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yes. I tried to use that, but none of it was working for my layout. I may have some fundamental errors in how I'm arranging things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the

```
.articlesubtitle {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

rule solves the problem.

```css
h3.articletitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

h4.articlesubtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

h5.articlesubtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F120B;
}

.articlesubtitle {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#toc_container {
    background: rgba(92, 9, 0, 0.14);
    border: 1px solid #4F120B;
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="book">
<h3 class="articletitle">Title</h3>
<article>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: auto;" id="toc_container">
<p class="toc_title">Contents</p>
<ul class="toc_list">
<li><a  href="#Scociety">Scociety</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#ArtHistory">Art</a></li>
<li><a href="#PopCulture">Pop Culture</a></li>
<li><a href="#HighCulture">High Culture</a></li>
<li><a href="#CommunicationAndTheSpreadOfIdeas">Communication And The Spread Of Ideas</a></li>
<li><a href="#Holidays">Holidays</a></li>
<li><a href="#GenderAndGenderRoles">Gender and Gender Roles</a></li>
<li><a href="#SubculturesAndAlternativeLifestyles">Subcultures and Alternative Lifestyles</a></li>
<li><a href="#UniversalFears">Universal Fears</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<h4 class="articlesubtitle" id="Scociety">Scociety</h4>
<h5 class="articlesubtitle" id="ArtHistory">Art</h5>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I worked that out thanks to a comment, but thank you so much for answering. I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "overflow: hidden;" to the CSS for headers resulted in the expected behavior.